# What are some recommended patterns for managing production deployments when using OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We're currently using ServiceStack with Entity Framework and are investigating moving to ServiceStack.OrmLite.

One major concern we have with it is how best to manage production deployments.

We use AppVeyor/Octopus for continuous deployment. With pure code-first EF we can use Migrations. With a DB-first approach, we've used DB Projects, SSDT & MsDeploy or tools like DbUp. But with OrmLite, we're not sure what the smoothest setup is to handle deployments to our test, staging & production DBs respectively. Should we go code-first and roll our own migration logic? Should we go DB-first and use T4 templates to generate POCO's?

I would be very interested to hear some success stories from people who've used OrmLite effectively in a continuous deployment setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst a crude approach, the way I've been handling schema migrations recently is by keeping all migrations in a Test Fixture that I manually run before deployment which just uses OrmLite to execute Custom SQL DDL statements to modify table schemas or populate any table data.

To switch between environments I just uncomment out the environment I want to run it on, e.g. here's an example of what my `DatabaseMigrations` test class looks like:

```
[TestFixture, Explicit]
public class DatabaseMigrations
{
    IDbConnectionFactory LocalDbFactory = ...;
    IDbConnectionFactory TestDbFactory = ...;
    IDbConnectionFactory LiveDbFactory = ...;

    private IDbConnection Db;

    public DatabaseMigrations()
    {
        //DbFactory = LocalDbFactory;
        //DbFactory = TestDbFactory;
        DbFactory = LiveDbFactory;
        Db = DbFactory.Open();
    }

    //...

    [Test]
    public void Add_ExternalRef_to_Subscription()
    {
        Db.ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER TABLE subscription ADD COLUMN external_ref text");

        var subIds = Db.Column<int>(Db.From<Subscription>().Where(
            x => x.ExternalRef == null).Select(x => x.Id));

        foreach (var subId in subIds)
        {
            Db.UpdateOnly(new Subscription { 
                    ExternalRef = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") 
                },
                where: x => x.Id == subId,
                onlyFields: x => new { x.ExternalRef });
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't support roll backs but it's quick and easy to create and keeps all schema changes in sequence in source control and runnable in code.

#### Bespoke solution with Custom Migrations Table

Other custom migration solutions which I've used previously successfully involve a bespoke solution maintaining a custom table in an RDBMS e.g. `Migrations` that has a list of all the migrations that have been run on that database. The CI Task would compare the rows in the database with the files in a local folder, e.g:

```
/Migrations
    01_Add_ExternalRef_to_Subscription.sql
```

and automatically run any missing custom sql migration scripts. This approach did a great job keeping the RDBMS table in-sync with the migration scripts where the state of what migrations were run on each db is kept in the DB itself.

The primary draw back of this solution was the migrations were kept in custom .sql files which lacked the flexibility of a proper programming language.

#### Optimal solution

I think the ideal solution would be a combination of these approaches, i.e. custom DB Migrations Table but instead running C# DB Migration NUnit tests instead. The DB Connection settings would also need to moved out into external configuration and potentially include a solution for rolling back schema migrations (e.g. tests ending with '_Rollback'), although the very few times I've needed to rollback, there's less effort in manually rolling back when needed then having to maintain rollback scripts for every schema change that's done.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response. I can't say I've ever used a migration rollback script either, to be honest. This gives us some great directions to move towards. I wonder if we could fork DbUp and tweak it to execute OrmLite DDL instead of just plain SQL scripts. To clarify - do you run those nunit tests in your CI to migrate DBs as well? Is ordering the tests a problem?

Comment: @Martaver I run them manually so ordering isn't a problem since I just append them to the end of the test, but yeah if you wanted CI to run them then you'd need to ensure ordering by prefixing with an ordered convention also you'd want to have some way where you'd only run the scripts that need to be run for each environment which is why the local Migrations table is a good idea so state of which scripts has been applied is kept with RDBMS table.

Comment: I just took a closer look at DbUp and it turns out you can actually drive each migration with DDL classes instead of SQL script (http://dbup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#code-based-scripts). We might give this a crack, so that we can package the DB migrations as a deployment artifact. One more question - do you build your migrations on top of a code-first model, or once you start using migrations do you switch to a DB-first/T4 approach?

Comment: @Martaver I always code-first i.e. never db-first. Even working on a legacy RDBMS, I'll normally create models manually. Sometimes I'll use OrmLite T4 templates to help with creating the initial POCO's, but then always code-first after that.

Comment: Cool, so then you end up with a workflow much like for EF Migrations. Sounds good! Thanks for your time!